# How should I select the correct path for doing my higher studies

Tags: masters, graduation

I have already completed my four year degree in Computer Science. Now I'm working as a trainee software engineer.However I wish to continue my studies further, and want to do a MSc or phd as I am interesting on doing higher studies. But I'm afraid of applying for a phd because I feel I'm not good enough to do a phd yet.(I have a second upper class). Therefore I think to follow a MSc and I'm very interesting in data science field. But I have doubt, whether I am going to take a right decision or not when selecting the path for doing higher studies. Please could some one help me to understand the way of selecting the correct path for doing higher studies for a fresh graduate student. Highly appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For physics PhDs in the UK, the minimum requirement is a 2:1 in your undergraduate degree, which you have (I say physics specifically because that is what I have experience with). However, applications are so competitive that you usually need above the bare minimum to be considered. This means either having a better grade in your undergrad or doing a Master's degree.

My suggestion to you is apply to both MScs and PhDs simultaneously. Then, if you get accepted to a PhD, great; if not, then do the MSc and apply for PhDs once you've done that. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll be applying for both MSc and phds. But I need some proper guidance to select the path for doing my higher studies. Thanks again

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "selecting the correct path". Only you know what's exactly right for you, all we can do is tell you how to get where you want to be.

Comment: Yep, I understand that my path should decide by myself. But I just try to understand whether selecting data science as a path for doing higher studies is a good choice for a fresh graduate like my self.

Comment: Six months ago I too was a fresh graduate student, but data science would not have been a good choice for me. Similarly, how can we tell whether it's a good choice for you? It's lucrative, certainly, and my impression is that it's a very quickly growing field of research-- but you might still hate it. Maybe try to get some experience in the field before committing to a research degree.

Comment: Ok, now I've got the idea. Thank You for your time & consideration.